# Height of objects not reducing when objects are hidden - Android layouts

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout containing two TextViews. I want the height of the LinearLayout to be fluid. When one of them is hidden, it should collapse to the height of the only visible Textview. I have specified the layout_height of the LinearLayout to "wrap_content" and set the visibility to invisible in the XML file. When I run the app, the layout is still the original size. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: set the visibility to gone instead of invisible

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, T0X1C. Worked!

Answer (score 13):

If possible paste your xml file.

And insted of setting visibility to invisible use `setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to do is change the visibility to gone.  A "gone" view will cause the others to behave as if it had never been added.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have the actual code present, it's really hard to tell a reason causing this issue. For general ideas, CSS style 'hidden' doesn't actually 'remove it' from the parent object displaying area. Instead, try display:none for what you are looking for.